# Some questions about social plugins (facebook, twitter, google+)

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus-one, google-plus

I have some questions regarding social plugins (facebook, twitter, google+).

By asking the following questions I would like you to take into considaration the following parameters: I want my website to be fast, Search Engine Optimzation..

1. Which of the social plugins above really affects SEO - Why and How?
2. Is it enough to put an anchor link to the page in the social network (facebook.com/page, twitter.com/page ...) or do I really need the +1 and Like button? - I know that lazy people like to click as little as possible, but do they really click without to see the page itself before?
3. What do you think is the ratio between clicking on the Like button to clicking on the like button inside the company page on facebook?

Thanks in advanced,
Din.

Answer (score 2):

> Which of the social plugins above really affects SEO - Why and How?

None of them help you with SEO and that's ok because that's not the point of them. They're they're to help you promote your website, they're not SEO tools.

> Is it enough to put an anchor link to the page in the social network (facebook.com/page, twitter.com/page ...) or do I really need the +1 and Like button? - I know that lazy people like to click as little as possible, but do they really click without to see the page itself before?

If you want the +1 and Like functionality to work you'll need to use whatever methods are available for each. If they offer plain text links to count +1's and Likes then you can use them. Otherwise you'll need to use the buttons. Keep in mind that users are more familiar with the buttons then not so if you deviate from this you better make it as intuitive as possible or likely see a reduced number of clicks.

Comment: John, i'd say the main benefit of the in page dynamic +1 and like buttons is better control over which urls are liked and tweeted, aside from convenience for users and keeping them on your site - would you agree?